# Is it possible to intercept messages from email address or phone number that is expired? if yes, how?

Tags: email, sms

I used to have an email account for receiving important messages but it was deleted by the email provider in which they claimed that deletion of the email address is still in progess but cannot be reversed. I desperately need that email address to receive important messages 
bascially i wonder if its still possible to intercept messages that were sent to the email address
If yes, how?
Also does this work on phone number as well? is it possible to intercept SMS that is sent to phone numbers
in which {the phone number) is no longer in service?

In other words---if someone send a message to that email address/phone number, is it possible to intercept that message before it reached the email address/phone number?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

The SMTP protocol has always had support for temporarily down servers. The nominal use case is that a message is submitted by a Mail User Agent (typically a mail reader like Thunderbird) to its closest Mail Transfert Agent (sendmail, postfix, exim, etc.), what is declared as the *SMTP server*.

Then the MTA tries to deliver the message either to a *forwarder* if it lacks connectivity (common in corporate network) or to a SMTP server that declares to be able to process the recipient mail address. Only one or many *relays* can be involved in the chain.

And each MTA on the chain is normally able to queue the message for a variable amount of time (generally between a few hours and a few days) until its next hop become up.

The only problem, is that there is no tool to discover where a mail can be queued. The only way I know is to contact the administrator of the first SMTP host and ask them whether the mail is still in their queue or was delivered and where, and iterate the chain until either you find the mail or you cannot obtain an answer from one of the admins.

Long story short, if you know the senders, the only reliable way it to ask them to send the mail to a different address. If you do not, and it the mail provider cannot resurect it in a short delay, I cannot imagine a way.

Comment: T_T so that means its not possible to do it...

Comment: same to phone number? : (

Comment: You cannot send a SMTP mail to a phone number. You can only send it to a mail address that is bound in any way to that phone number. You have to use different protocols (SMS, MMS, probably other proprietary protocols) to send a non SMTP message to a phone number.